# Pass path Param to render() function of Route in Switch - React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My component CompanyProfile is a hook.  But I prefer using switch with React Router.  How can I get `:name` which is an expected prop of `CompanyProfile` that I send via `<Link />` in the uri sent as a prop to my `CompanyProfile` component specified in in render?

```js
const App = () => (
  <>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/company/:name"
        render={(props:RouteComponentProps) => (
          <CompanyProfile {...props} findCompany={findCompany} />
        } />
    ...
```

The reason I used render is because I also needed to pass in a `findCompany` function as a prop to the component.

In another component I have a Link to this route:

```
<Link to={`/company/${company.name}`} >
  <img alt="company profile image" src={companyUrl} />
</Link>
```

so I'm trying to get this Link to work.

Just in case this helps, here is my entire Switch:

```
const App = () => (
  <>
    <Switch>
      <Route component={withTracker(HomePageContainer)} exact path="/" />
      <Route component={Build} exact path="/build" />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/company/:name"
        render={(props:RouteComponentProps) => (
          <CompanyProfile {...props} findCompany={findCompany} />
        } />
        <Route
          component={withTracker(CompanyDetailContainer)}
          name="companydetail"
          path="/companies/:companyId/details" />
        <Route component={withTracker(InterviewContainer)} name="company" path="/interviews/companies/:companyId" />
        <Route component={withTracker(About)} name="about" path="/about" />
        <Route component={withTracker(Container)} path="/" />
        <Route component={withTracker(NotFound)} path="*" />
     </Switch>
  <RenderRoute />
</>
);
```

And here is part of `CompanyProfile.tsx`.  I tried the suggestion to get it through match props but I still need to type this somehow because it doesn't understand `match.params` yet:

```
    interface interface CrafterProfileProps {
        name: string;
        findCompany: (name: string) => Promise<Company>;
    }
    
    const CompanyProfile = (props: CompanyProfileProps) => {
        const { findCompany } = props;
        const { name } = props.match.params;
        const [company, setCompany] = useState<Company>();
...
```

The last time I was able to get to match was using withRouter but I'd prefer not to use HOCs like that.  And this is a Hook Component so is there a way I can add a TypeScript type to my function that allows me to get at `match` here?

**Attempt 2** (I'm also not very good at TS)
this didn't work, it still complains it doesn't know match but:

```js
interface CompanyProfileProps {
    findCompany: (name: string) => Promise<Company>;
    props: RouteComponentProps<{ name?: string }>;
}

const CompanyProfile = (props: CompanyProfileProps) => {
    const { findCompany } = props;
    const { name } = props.props.match.params;
```

**Final**

I was not able to get TS typed and working inside my component so I went the other route proposed by the answer and this is what worked:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/company/:name"
  render={(props:RouteComponentProps<{name: string}>) => {
    const { name } = props.match.params;
    return (<CompanyProfile findCompany={findCompany} name={name} />);
}} />
```

If anyone has a better way to do this I am all ears but this works for now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CompanyProfile` is being rendered by a `Route`'s `render` prop and since you are correctly passing [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) through to it you can simply access via the [`match`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match) prop (`props.match.params.name`).

[Edit]

If Typescript is complaining about the route props you can pull out the match param and pass on to route component. Pass *only* the props declared in your interface.

```
render={(props: RouteComponentProps) => {
  const { name } = props.match.params;
  return (
    <CompanyProfile
      findCompany={findCompany}
      name={name}
    />
  );
}}
```

An alternative is to declare a union of your `CompanyProfileProps` and the `RouteComponentProps` interfaces. I'm not very familiar with typescript so I won't pretend to know the syntax there, but I know you *can* do that.

Comment: the problem is TS is complaining that I'm not passing the name because it's an expected prop.  So I tried `<CompanyProfile {...props} findCompany={findCompany} name="" />` but seems like then, name isn't being sent from the url after I do that, probably because I'm hard coding it?

Comment: also if I try using that for my component, it doesn't know what match is, so I guess now I need to specify Router props in my component.. for TS. See my updated post.

Comment: thank you very much, I said screw TS and went with your first solution.  If anyone knows how to properly type TS in my component let me know though.  I am updating the post with what worked via your solution.